# Compute a “mirror”, where the first half of the image is copied, flipped (l-r) and then copied into the second half using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensorflow

I want to solve this problem using tensorflow but I searched the web and found git issue#206 states that indexing and slicing is still not supported on a tensor variable initialized from a numpy array.

Otherwise I would have done...

```
image = mpimg.imread(filename)
height, width, depth = image.shape
x = tf.Variable(image, name='x')
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    result = session.run(x[::1,:width*0.5,::1]) #this step is not possible
```

What shall I use??

Comment: Do you want to create a node in the Tensorflow graph that produces the mirrored image, or do you just want to have the result in a numpy array? (to plot it for instance)

Comment: A node would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `tf.slice` and `tf.reverse`, and then concatenate the results.

```py
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [height, width, depth])

half_left = tf.slice(image, [0, 0, 0], [height, width/2, depth])
half_right = tf.reverse(half_left, [False, True, False])

res = tf.concat(1, [half_left, half_right])
```

The code will also work with a Variable.

Answer (score -1):

I also struggled with that one in the Tensor Flow tutorial, here is the whole code that will achieve what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
# First, load the image again
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = dir_path + "/MarshOrchid.jpg"
image = mpimg.imread(filename)
height, width, depth = image.shape

# Create a TensorFlow Variable
x = tf.Variable(image, name='x')


model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    left_part = tf.slice(x, [0, 0, 0], [height, width/2, depth]) #Extract Left part
    rigth_part = tf.slice(x, [0, width/2, 0], [height, width/2, depth]) #Extract Right part
    left_part = tf.reverse_sequence(left_part, np.ones((height,)) * width/2, 1, batch_dim=0) #Reverse Left Part
    rigth_part = tf.reverse_sequence(left_part, np.ones((height,)) * width/2, 1, batch_dim=0) #Reverse Right Part
    x = tf.concat([left_part, rigth_part],1) #Concat them together along the second edge (the width)

    result = session.run(x)


print(result.shape)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

These code is the solution for the last exercise of [this tutorial.](http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson3/)

Comment: If this is a new question, please ask it by clicking the
[Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps
provide context. If this is an answer, please make it more clear.

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).